# Unexpedted error has occured in sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

There is Sharepoint 2010 Document center site when i browse its throw unexpected error in browser when i restart IIS site works fine but again everyday morning site not working and i saw below errors

> Application error when access /sites/93/default.aspx, Error=Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided,
>   or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070542)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)      at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
>
> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. Either a
>   required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided
>   impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)      at
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

there is permissions exists in wfe server

SPFarm or app pool have policy accesss.

locat security >> impersonate a client after authentification > add user

Comment: did you recently change the credentials of the farm user/ web application user?

Comment: yes i changed the spfarm,application pool accounts password, site works everytime i restart IIS

Comment: try to update the application pool identity again, go to application pool then advanced setting and change the identity by retying the credentials, after that recycle the application pool. hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if you have updated the password of the account in application pools in IIS.
2. Start full user synchronization in user profile service application.
3. Run SharePoint 2010 product configuration wizard.